# What is this symbol called? A blue rectangle with a red dot

Tags: rf, symbol, energy-harvesting

[image]
This is a rectifier circuit in RF Energy Harvesting. I have no idea what does the blue rectangle symbol called. (Found in https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d6fe/47f5539a231dfeeef67166977893070788f2.pdf)

Comment: I don't know either, what's this from? "RF energy harvesting" isn't a useful description; what software or book or whatever did you find this image in?

Comment: I found from this link https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d6fe/47f5539a231dfeeef67166977893070788f2.pdf

Comment: ADS does that and I must say that I can't get on with their peculiarities.

Comment: In the article the circuit is called a rectifier. It is also mentioned that Schottky diodes are used for this rectifier. So my guess is that the di_hp_... symbols are simply **diodes**. How anyone would publish an article with a schematic with such weird symbols is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: @AchariyaRojbundit:  The two components like that are diodes.  The box and the dot seem to be related to how the simulation software handles the simulation model of the component. If you look closely, you'll see the type of diode encoded in the text attached to the box.  They are using [HSMS2850 RF diodes.](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/57844.pdf)

Comment: The circuit itself is a simple [Greinacher voltage doubler.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_doubler#Greinacher_circuit) It makes DC out of the RF.

Answer (score 1):

The symbols with the red dots are schottky diodes, as Bimpelrekkie stated in comments.

The red dot indicates the unused pin.  This device comes in a SOT23-3 package, which has 3 pins, of which only two are used.  I don't know why they used a 3-pin model in ADS for this, since you don't do pcb layout in ADS, and don't care about that 3rd pin for RF simulation.

Well, no one I know uses ADS for PCB layout (and I work in an RF design group).

Comment: so the red dot is because it's unconnected?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.  I think it is a visual aid to indicate to the user that they left a pin unconnected.  In this case, it doesn't matter since that pin is unused.